Google Services in ESRI Applications
Our current situation:
We are using ESRI technology (JS SDK on the frontend; ESRI Portal / Server on the backend). We want to implement Google routing and geolocation services (using our own API key of course). We have read in some forums that Google doesn't allow users to integrate their services in other mapping frameworks like Leaflet or OpenLayers.
What we want to do:

write our own Geolocator to be used in ESRI out-of-the-box applications and when connected to our portal also in our custom JS applications
make queries to the routing services and convert the results to GeoJSON (or any other format) that can be placed as a graphic on the ESRI JS map or scene

Questions:

are there any sources regarding the current legal situation using Google services in ESRI applications

are there any good alternatives with the same level of accuracy like Google provides



Google mentions in their terms of use that the Geolocation API can only be used on a Google map: "It is prohibited to use Geolocation API data on a map that is not a Google map."
Do you need a world wide geolocator? If it's for a region where you have good data, you could create your own locator.

Yes, we would need a global available locator. In best the same quality as Google suggestions should be created. I guess with this restriction we can't use Google within ESRI at all.
